# Not able to see certain Hystrix metric in Graphite

Tags: graphite, hystrix

I am trying to publish Hystrix stream to Graphite/Grafana setup.
I am using this docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/choopooly/grafana-graphite/
I am not able to see following metric which is sent by Hystrix but apparently dropped by Graphite.

```
[debug] c.n.s.p.g.GraphiteMetricObserver - alphanew.HystrixCommand.MessageCommand.isCircuitBreakerOpen false 1487957855
```

`[debug] c.n.s.p.g.GraphiteMetricObserver - alphanew.HystrixCommand.MessageCommand.currentTime 1487957855480 1487957855`

```
[debug] c.n.s.p.g.GraphiteMetricObserver - alphanew.HystrixCommand.MessageCommand.countBadRequests 0 1487957855
```

Out of these metrics I cannot see isCircuitBreakerOpen in either Graphite/Grafana?

When I check this path /var/lib/graphite/storage/whisper/alphanew/HystrixCommand/MessageCommand,
I can see countBadRequests.wsp and currentTime.wsp but not isCircuitBreakerOpen.wsp.

Any suggestions?